# If $X, Y$ are independent, then $E(Y\mid X) = E(Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

For random variables $X, Y$, I need to show that if $X, Y$ are independent, then $E(Y\mid X) = E(Y)$. To do so, it suffices to prove that for any $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ measurable (Borel), we have that
$$\int_{X \in B}EYdP = \int_{X \in B}Y dP$$

I know that $\int_{X \in B}EYdP = EYP(X\in B)$ - but how do I show that $\int_{X \in B}Y dP = EY P(X \in B)$?

Comment: *Hint.* $X$ and $Y$ independent $\implies$ $\mathbf1_{\{X\in B\}}$ and $Y$ independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ being $\sigma (X)-$measurable. What has to be proved is $$\mathbb E[Y\boldsymbol 1_A]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y]\boldsymbol 1_A],$$
but this is straightforward since $$\mathbb E[Y\boldsymbol 1_A]=\mathbb E[Y]\mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_A],$$
since $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y).$
Since $f_{Y\vert X=x}(x,y)=\dfrac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}=\dfrac{f_X(x)f_Y(y)}{f_X(x)}=f_Y(y)\implies$
$$\mathbb E[Y\vert X=x]=\int_{\mathbb R}yf_{Y\vert X=x}(x,y)dy=\int_{\mathbb R}yf_Y(y)dy=\mathbb E[Y].$$
Now you can easily find $\mathbb E[Y\vert X].$

Comment: Why $X$ and $Y$ should be continuous ?